# Extracting duration values of silence and sound intervals

Tags: praat

I am looking to extract the duration values of silence and sound intervals from the text grid. I have broken down the audio file by sounding and speech intervals, as well as durations. However, I do not know how or if this is possible to extract the duration of each.

Does anyone have some input?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you are just interested in duration, you can process your Textgrid file with R and packages such as rPraat or PraatR.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest form of extracting is to save the text grid and find the start and end values for each frame. You will be reading a series of "intervals" numbered 1 to N, looking at the "text" value in that interval, and the duration is xmax-xmin. This can be done with your favorite programming language, using the text grid as the input file; then you decide what you want to do with the durations. If you want to do it the hard way and write a Praat script, you can also do that. But there is no pre-set button that writes all of the durations of intervals indicated in a text grid.